# function Copy() in Free Pascal

Tags: delphi, copy, freepascal

Delphi allows 3 versions of the `Copy` function:

```
function CopyTest(const S: string): string;
begin
  Result:= Copy(S, 1, 5);
  Result:= Copy(S, 1);
//  Result:= Copy(S);   //  not allowed for strings, allowed for dyn arrays
end;
```

FreePascal seems to compile only the 1st (3-arg) version; for the others I have compile-time error

```
Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "$fpc_ansistr_copy"
```

Am I missing some FPC compiler switch or `Copy` overloads are not available in Free Pascal?

Comment: Just to add; here's a [`reference`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/rtl/system/copy.html) for it. However it doesn't mean it's actual with a current RTL code.

Comment: @TLama - I don't think RTL code matters, the compiler determines what function to call. 'Fpc_Ansistr_Copy' is in astrings.inc anyway, AFAICT there're no overloads to it.

Comment: +1 for noticing a bug. Reported as http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=22964 (see comments in Sertac's answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'copy' node generator code is in `inline_copy` function of [`pinline.pas`](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/branches/fixes_2_6_0/compiler/pinline.pas?view=markup) of FPC sources. Only for dynamic arrays variants 1 and 3 are valid (which generates code to pass -1 for second and third parameters to `fpc_dynarray_copy` in case of variant 3). For all other cases (ansi string, wide string, unicode string, char(*) and short string) 3 parameters are required (compiler generates a call to one of the copy functions (e.g. `fpc_ansistr_copy` in `astrings.pas`) without checking parameters, since the called function has no overloads or default parameters an exact match of parameters is required). No switches/directives involved.

(*) <sub>This one is a bit weird, it returns a **shortstring** of either itself or ''.</sub>

Comment: +1 good assessment. Basically three param string is the original, and the dynamic array version was later added. Strange that it was never found (since it probably is that way since 2005). Please file a bug.

Comment: @Marco - Thank you! Which bug are you referring to? I though all of it was as designed.

Comment: Sertac wasn't asking *where* to file the bug, @Marco. He was asking *which* bug to file. I see no bug here. Free Pascal requires all three parameters for the string version of `Copy`, which is the same as Delphi's requirement. It's only the *array* version that makes the latter parameters optional.

Comment: Delphi (XE) accepts the second form for strings, FPC (all current versions, in Delphi mode) not, with the error in the original post. When I wrote it, I assumed Delphi also allowed the third form for strings, but testing shows it doesn't. Maybe my remark should have been for the toplevel post, and not Sertac's though. Anyway, I filed the bug myself to avoid confusion, http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=22964

Comment: Strange, I was pretty sure the parameterless version of `Copy` function is allowed for strings too and it is a functional version of `UniqueString` procedure. But yes, Delphi (XE) does not allow it.

Answer (score 4):

As I know the Free Pascal support default value parameters, so there is no need for overloading function. You can writte new `Copy` function something like...

```
function Copy(const S: string; From: integer = 1; Count: integer = MaxInt): string;
begin
//There is no need to check the string length
//      if Count > Length(S) then
//        Count := Length(S);
        result := system.Copy(S, From, Count);
end;
```

Comment: I think, you don't even need to care if the count exceed the string length (but haven't verified this).

Comment: You don't need to check the length. I have often used it with a longer length. (assuming MaxInt is not so large, it causes a int overflow somewhere in copy)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, since the question does not ask how the issue could be solved. Even if that was not the case, since your function is not a compiler intrinsic, it would need overloads for other types than strings, which would again render this a non-answer.